# What makes for a good answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

I found myself looking for some place to point a new user on why his answer wasn't a good answer. I couldn't find anything except the fairly unhelpful [Help page's "How do I write a good answer"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

So, I'm putting it to the community. What makes for a *good* code review? What are the essential parts? What pitfalls should we avoid?

I think [this answer to a different question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/913/41243) is a pretty good start.

Comment: Related: [Checklist or General Directions on how to write a good CR-ish answer](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1990/checklist-or-general-directions-on-how-to-write-a-good-cr-ish-answer)

Answer (score 4):

In a different context, I listed [contents of a good answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1440/9357).

I'll do something slightly different here, which is to list some *attributes* of a good answer.  Good answers…

- [are entertaining and memorable, yet serious, and point out unexpected issues, especially security holes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/48004/9357)
- [have visual impact](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/48698/9357)
- [are tailored to the context of the question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/38526/9357)
- [recommend fresh solutions and alternative platforms, if justified](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/54243/9357)
- [reveal the reviewer's train of thought, if it's spaghetti code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/53969/9357)
- [consider issues beyond the code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46984/9357)

Comment: Would you consider adding something like - aim to educate about not just what but *why* a change is suggested